# What is this spam bot trying to do by filling in my PHP forms randomly?

Tags: spam

I have been getting a lot of bot spam lately. The most recent one has this as the body:

> already to standards Address is is required return
>   ?  then with local include accurate Another they in  ?  and make items
>   the still their and a  ?  solitary of suspend My still buy Australia, the
>   ?  safe to of security to totality. requirements. locations

Can someone please explain what they are trying to do by just putting random words in my text box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm violating this site's guidelines by merely speculating, but my guess is that Attacking Host A tries to insert [some string] onto your site through a form and Attacking Host B tries to read [some string] from your site. You may notice the attempt and may blacklist the IP address of the form spammer, but if you are vulnerable the real attack won't come from that IP address. The form spammer is a disposable scout; it simply "tags" sites as vulnerable and moves on.